# PHPunit name space class not found

Tags: php, namespaces, phpunit

I use phpunit for test my codes

And use namespaces, but on run command line i get error

Code.php :

```
<?php
namespace Check;

class Code {
    private $code;

    public function set($code){
        $this->ensureIsValidCode($code);
        $this->code = $code;

        return $this->code;
    }

    private function ensureIsValidCode($code) {
        if(!is_numeric($code) || strlen($code) != 5) {
            echo "Not valid code : ".$code.PHP_EOL;
            exit();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

CodeTest.php

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Check\Code as Code;

final class CodeTest extends TestCase {
    public function testSet(){
        $random = 34211;
        $code = new Code();
        $res = $code->set($random);

        $this->assertEquals($res, 34211);
    }
}
?>
```

Error :

```
1) CodeTest::testSet
Error: Class 'Check\Code' not found
```

Command Line :

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests/CodeTest
```

But i use require file, work fine

Comment: Have you specified `tests` to be a PSR-4 root in your composer file?

Comment: @apokryfos no i dont use it. how can i ?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4

Comment: @apokryfos i use it : "autoload": {
      "classmap": [
          "src/"
      ]
  }

Comment: Add an extra entry `"psr-4": { "": "tests/" }` or (recommended) use `Tests` as your root namespace and add `"psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" }` and change your `Check` namespace to `Tests\Check`

Comment: @apokryfos thx, work fine